# Can PFBC (Php form builder class) submit JSON objects?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

So, I recently stumbled across PFBC, and I must say that it seems very appealing to me!

In considering to use it, I have only one main concern: I really **hate the $_POST array(s)**, which is why I always use a javascript function to submit forms, that submits one (or several) nice JSON stings, which I can then extract to objects, and I really **like objects**!

After quite a bit of Google'ing, I haven't been able to figure out if this is possible with PFBC? Ideally, it would just be something one could configure, but I have a feeling it's not that simple (yet, hopefully)?

Comment: On further investigation, an anonymous function is actually bound to the submit button, which seems to be supposed to serialize the form into a JSON string, but for some reason it doesn't work?! data: jQuery("#$id").serialize(),

Comment: if the data being set in a jQuery.ajax call if you you need to set the dataType to json.

Comment: sorry it's not dataType that needs to be set ... it is `processData: false` should be done [here](http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/source/browse/trunk/PFBC/Form.php#350)

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference at all, I still get the traditional $_POST array. If I try to do this: data: JSON.stringify(objectifyArray($("#$id").serializeArray())), I get an error that I can't read before the page submits (because of the error :/)

Comment: well worst case if you want the syntatic sugar of using an object on the receiving end there is nothing preventing you from casting the $_POST array to an object. `$data = (object)$_POST;`

Comment: and if you wanted nested arrays to become objects you could do `$data = json_decode(json_encode($_POST));`

Comment: The only problem with that is that checkboxes unchecked leaves a gap in the $_POST['checkbox'], thus making it difficult to handle several forms at once. Submitting objects solves this, because the properties are always set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out have to force a submit of a JSON string.

Basically [this line](https://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/source/browse/trunk/PFBC/Form.php#353) has to be changed to this:

> data: {data: JSON.stringify(objectifyArray($("#" +
>   $id.id).serializeArray()))}

**Explanation**: `#$id` is written in php, and you'd expect it to be the id of the form in question (which Jquery somehow interprets it as) with an appended "#" for jquery, as is normally the case when including variables in strings. However, it's actually the whole damn form in a text-string (I have no idea how/why though :/), therefor `"#" + $id.id` has to replace it, to get the actual ID-property of the form in question.

After that's done, it's just a matter of formatting the form to a correct JSON string, which the line does, with the help of objectifyArray and the JSON.js javascript library.

```
function objectifyArray(a)
{
    var o = {};
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
}
```